# One-dimensional circular Conway's Game of Life

Tags: java, array, time-limit-exceeded, game-of-life

I have a program that is working, but it takes way too long to get the answer. With input like

```
15 100000000
111010111001100
```

The program checks for 15 numbers, and checks if two number beside the numbers in the second row adds up to exactly 1. If it adds up to 1, then the number would stay/change to 1, otherwise it change/stay 0. And this need to happen for 100000000 times (it changes each time). Right now I can get the right answer, but it takes like 1 minute to get it.

```
import java.util.*;
public class circle {
final Scanner in;
public circle()
{
   in=new Scanner(System.in);
   run();
   in.close();
}
public void run()
{
   String input=in.nextLine();
   //I created two arrays, checks for one array while change the other one so the changed number wouldn't affect other checking
   final int[] list=createarray(input);
   final int totalcells=list[0];
   final int generation=list[1];
   String input1=in.nextLine();
   long[] deadalive=createarray2(input1,totalcells);
   long[] changing=new long[totalcells];
   System.arraycopy(deadalive,0,changing,0,totalcells);
   //It checks for y times and checks all the cells
   for(int y=0;y<generation;y++)
   {
       for(int x=0;x<totalcells;x++)
       {
           if(x==0)
           {
               if(deadalive[x+1]+deadalive[totalcells-1]==1)
               {
                changing[x]=1;  
               }
               else
                   changing[x]=0;

           }
           else if(x==totalcells-1)
           {

                   if(deadalive[x-1]+deadalive[0]==1)
                   {
                       changing[x]=1;
                   }
                   else
                       changing[x]=0;
           }
           else
           {
                   if(deadalive[x-1]+deadalive[x+1]==1)
                   {
                       changing[x]=1;
                   }
                   else
                       changing[x]=0;   
           }
       }
       //make two arrays the same after each changes
       System. arraycopy(changing, 0, dead alive, 0, changing.length);

   }
   System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(changing));

}
private static int[] createarray(String input)
{
   final String[] args=input.trim().split("\\s+");
    final int aray[]=new int[2];
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        aray[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    return aray;
}
private static long[] createarray2(String input1,int totalcells)
{
   final long array[]=new long[totalcells];
    for(int i=0;i<input1.length();i++)
    {
        array[i]=Character.digit(input1. charAt(i),10);
    }
    return array;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
   new circle();
}
}
```

This code is supposed to change the second row of numbers like input:

```
7 1
0000001
```

Output would be:

```
1000010
```

0 changes to 1 if the two "neighbor" adds up to 1 exactly. other wise they are 0, but this one only runs for one time unit, where there are ones that needs to run 10000000 time units. For loop probably isn't efficient enough to do it in a short time period, so I thought maybe there are better ways to do it.

Comment: For completeness, could you include the code for `createarray()` and `createarray2()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea to speed things up, given that the input is only 15 numbers:

- Since the numbers are binary, you could represent the board as a bitmask in an integer instead of an array (see [wikipedia/masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing))).
- There are only \$2^{15}\$ possible states. You could create a `Map<Integer, Integer>` from each state bitmask to the next. Then each iteration in your algorithm is gonna be a simple map lookup.

There are more optimizations you could to make it even faster, but this should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you represent your string on 2nd line as a binary number, then your inner `for` loop (i.e. the part which finds 'changing') simply becomes bit operations (see below). Then, if your number of generations is greater than \$2^{totalCells}\$ you use the hashmap optimization suggested.

If your 2nd line bits are a0a1a2a3 (where ai is ith bit) then the changing is simply a1a2a3a0 ^ a3a0a1a2.

For example, if 's' is your string on 2nd line, and your `totalCells` is less than 64 (so as to represent in `unsigned int`) then:

1. Done outside the `for` loops to init `curNumber`:

   ```
   unsigned int curNumber = 0; 
   unsigned int maskHigh = 0x1, maskLow = 0x1, mask=0;
   for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); ++k) {
       curNumber = curNumber << 1 | (s[k] - '0'); // s[k] is s.at(k)
       maskHigh <<= 1;
       mask = (mask << 1) | 0x1;
   }
   maskHigh >>= 1;
   ```
2. Each inner `for` loop simply becomes:

   ```
   unsigned int shiftedLeft = curNumber << 1 & (mask) | ((maskHigh & curNumber) >> s.length()-1); 
   unsigned int shiftedRight = curNumber >> 1 & (mask) | ((maskLow & curNumber) << s.length()-1);

   changing = shiftedLeft ^ shiftedRight;
   curNumber = changing;
   ```

Comment: Do you mind explaining how your maskLow and maskHigh values work, and what are their initial values?

Comment: sorry. I had left that line out (added now). Also added explanation using bits a0a1a2a3.